# The difference between commands under build process and in shell

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have such `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
RUN gem install bundle
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
COPY . /app
RUN bundle install
```

And `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
    db_data:
```

I'm entering container and run `bundle install` command:

```
docker-compose run web bundle install
```

It has no error:

```
...
Bundle complete! 28 Gemfile dependencies, 98 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `/usr/local/bundle`
```

But when I'm building the container it produces some error:

```
docker-compose build web

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activemodel (= 5.2.1)

  In Gemfile:
    activeresource was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
activemodel-serializers-xml (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends
on
        activemodel (> 5.x)

    activeresource was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (< 6, >= 5.0)

    carrierwave was resolved to 1.2.3, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

    protected_attributes was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
      activemodel (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0.beta)

    rails (= 5.2.1) was resolved to 5.2.1, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 6
```

I'm trying to understand what is the difference between these environments(?): the build process and shell but the command `bundle install` is same.

Why the build process produces the error?

P.S.

```
docker image list                                                                                                           docker●[ruby-2.5.1p57]
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              6f5884e6a480        2 minutes ago       987MB
dev_web             latest              44c878bad0f2        About an hour ago   1.21GB
<none>              <none>              ca720e782976        3 hours ago         1.21GB
ruby                2.5                 34d1c6024e99        37 hours ago        869MB

docker ps -a                                                                                                                docker●[ruby-2.5.1p57]
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                               NAMES
bbd1c5dfd92b        6f5884e6a480        "/bin/sh -c 'bundle …"   55 seconds ago      Exited (6) 39 seconds ago                                       elated_meitner
```

Comment: what's docker-compose***r***?

Comment: @wotanii, sorry, typo, fixed

Comment: Maybe you can also share Gemfile and/or Gemfile.lock?

Comment: So there are a few problems with this.

1) If you can `docker-compose run` a container, that means it's ALREADY BUILT somehow.
2) If there is an image already built, it is different from the one you are currently trying to build (meaning it could have been a change in the Gemfile).

Please list your relevant docker images with `docker image list` and the containers with `docker ps -a`.  Otherwise this question isn't exactly answerable.

Comment: @Julian, I've put the info you've asked. Yes, the images are built. What I need to understand the difference between running container and entering container with bash. Maybe it's different user or something else

Comment: Commands you use with run start in new containers with configuration defined by that of the service, including volumes, links, and other details.
See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Comment: The Gemfile you are using seems to have a conflict.

protected_attributes was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
      activemodel (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0.beta)

The activemodel version required cannot simultaneously have version <5.0 and >5.0.

Not sure why the already built "web" image allows you to run 'bundle install' but I suspect the gemfile copied into that image is different from the one you are currently copying during the 'build' command

Can you run 'docker-compose run web cat /app/Gemfile' and post the output?

Comment: @sxm1972 and Julian I understood what is going on in my environment, the rails error mixed up with my bad awareness of docker. You guys should've write some answers below to earn scores and my appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `docker-compose build web` it will try to build the docker image according to the specifications in the Dockerfile. When you run `docker-compose run web XXX` it will run the container web with the command XXX for the *existing* image. That means the commands in the Dockerfile will not be executed. Most likely the error comes from a misconfiguration in the Gemfile, but I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 1):

The difference originates in the volume you're mapping in `docker-compose.yaml`. It overwrites the last four steps of your `Dockerfile`. Specifically, you seem to have different `Gemfile` building the container and running the container.

If you skip mounting the volume, you should get the same error when trying to `install` in the running container.